# How to get Paging info and a single record when using OData in ASP.NET 5 WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata, asp.net5

I have an web API written using C# on the top of ASP.NET 5/core with EntityFrameworkCore.

I am using [OData](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/) to apply filters on when querying the database.

Currently, I am allowing query options by doing this in my controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DbContext _db;

    public ProductsController(DbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All, AllowedFunctions = AllowedFunctions.AllFunctions, MaxTop = 500)]
    public IQueryable<TModel> Search()
    {
        return db.Products;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All, AllowedFunctions = AllowedFunctions.AllFunctions)]
    public TModel First()
    {
        // How could I apply the query filters here before I execute the query?
        return db.Products.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

### Questions

In the `Search` action, how can I return the records in addition to the paganing info like `totalPagesAvailable` and `totalRecordsAvailable`?

In the `First` action, how can I apply the query filters to the query before I return the first matching record?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All, AllowedFunctions = AllowedFunctions.AllFunctions)]
public Product First(ODataQueryOptions<Product> queryOptions)
{
    var query = (IQueryable<Product>)queryOptions.ApplyTo(db.Products);
    return query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: I can't seems to be able to try it because it broke my Swagger UI. Any idea how I can use ODataQueryOptions with swaggerUI?